# Increase mouse pointer speed in System Shock Portable

Tags: dosbox, system-shock

I'm running System Shock Portable v1.2 and when I increase the resolution to 1024x768 or higher the mouse pointer speed slows down incredibly making the game nearly unplayable (I have to move my mouse 3-4 times to get the pointer across the screen).

Is there some config file setting to increase the speed of the mouse pointer? I am using Malba Tahan's mouselook mod as well as Gulikoza's DOSBox build if that makes a difference.

Edit: In `XCYB.CFG` I decreased the `hmousemul` and `vmousemul` to 1 which makes it playable but is there any other tweak that can be done to increase the speed of the cursor even a little more?

Comment: wait wait wait System Shock... Portable? Please tell me what this is and where I might acquire it. I am long overdue for a SHODAN fix.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz http://www.systemshock.org/index.php?topic=211.0 Portable, as in you can put it on a USB stick, doesn't require an "install". Also has a few patches and improvements to make it playable on modern systems.

Comment: You can check out my video on it: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YdbgTUA9YdU using Mouse Look mod.

Comment: @Solivagant If it were possible I'd slap you through TCP/IP for saying System Shock is the "granddaddy of BioShock" in your YouTube video info.

Comment: @I take Drukqs Well, it has audio logs! And Shock in the name... :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In DOSBox, the mouse sensitivity can be altered by changing the setting "sensitivity" in section [sdl] in the file "Dosbox.conf".

The default value is 100 and can be changed up to 1000.

I don't know if this is helpful for you in this situation but it might be worth a try.

http://www.dosbox.com/wiki/Dosbox.conf

Comment: After a quick test this seems to work. I'm not sure how I missed this before, maybe I thought 100 was the maximum. A value of about 800 seems to be good to be good on my system with the xcyb.cfg changes I already made.

Comment: Glad to help. Being new to this community, every accepted answer makes me throw a party. :-)